# What is the incentive for the in-season tournament?

Tags: basketball, nba

The NBA commenced an in-season tournament in 2023. The winner of this in-season tournament receives the NBA Cup.

I've seen the financial incentive - a prize pool that increases the better a team finishes in the tournament. The games outside the in-season tournament finals will count as regular season games.

Are there incentives beyond the prize pool and bragging rights for the NBA Cup?

Comment: Aside from the championship game, all tournament games count towards the regular-season standings, so I don't see why there would be any additional incentive to play and win those games compared to any other regular season game.